# Selection for last date is still retaining in multiselect jquery-Ui-Datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using Jquery-ui-datepicker as inline with multidate: true. when i select multiple dates and click outside the calendar still the last selected date is highlighted. I want to remove the highlight when we click outside the calendar after the dates got selected

I have tried to remove the active class from the date, but what is ts doing is from UI the highlight is going Off, but the datepicker is not updated, so when i click on other date both the dates are getting highlighted.

Another issue is like if i call update method, it is working fine but the thing is the calendar is resetted to current month.
I want to stay in the month where the user selected the dates, for example, i am selecting dates in November, if i update the datepicker, it is showing the "September" month which is current month.

```
$('.date').datepicker()
            var new_options = {
                multidate: true,
                startDate: new Date,
                todayHighlight: true,
                // daysOfWeekHighlighted: [0, 6],
                endDate: new Date('12/31/2050'),
                dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
                beforeShowDay: function(date){
                    let formattedDate = moment(date).format("MM/DD/YYYY");

                    if ($.inArray(formattedDate, already_active_generalHolidays) != -1){
                      return {
                         classes: 'generalHolidayClass'
                      };
                    } 
}
```